# Gathering dynamic volume of columns

Tags: r

Each month I append data to a table.  I want to plot this data (ggplot2) each month.  My challenge is gathering the data each month, as the data grows by at least one column every month.

The data frame consists of 2 rows, then one column of factor type, and then the rest of the columns are num type.  The following code generates the correct table, but each month, I would have to add a new column to the gather statement.

I tried to leave out the column names but the result was not acceptable.

```
Gatherresult <- gather(df, "Jan 19", "Feb 19", "Mar 19", 
                       "Apr 19", "May 19", "Jun 19", key = "Product", value = "Volume")
```

I'm looking for a means of gathering all columns in the table.  Column 1 would be the factor, Column 2 would be each product per factor (column 1) and Column 3 would be the volumes per Product (column 2) per factor (column 1).

Comment: Try `gather(df, Product, Volume, `Jan 19`:`Jun 19`)` note the backquotes

Comment: The default is to gather all columns, so `gather(df, Product, Volume)` may work. You can also use the `dplyr` select helpers, e.g., `gather(df, key = Product, Volume, ends_with("19"))`. If you post a little sample data we can test our guesses at solutions...

Comment: Not sure how to copy a table into this platform yet, so commas will separate the columns:

'Designation, Jan 19, Feb 19, Mar 19,...
Earn, 25, 35, 42,...
Non-Earn, 33, 55, 10,...'

When I gather the data, this is the result I want and am getting:

'Designation, Product, Volume
Non-Earn, Jan 19, 33
Earn, Jan 19, 25
Non-Earn, Feb 19, 55
Earn, Feb 19, 42'
...

I've tried leaving out the column names, but then the result is only 2 columns and Designation is not correct.  I'm looking to plot Earn vs Non-Earn for many, many products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the example data you gave in the comments, which I've reformatted to make it easy to input:

```
 df <- data.frame(Designation = c("NonR", "R"),
             "Jan 19" = c(3529735, 12092371),
             "Feb 19" = c(359615, 2810619),
             "Mar 19" = c(13860320, 7110432),
             "Apr 19" = c(31385, 1304819),
             "May 19" = c(33026202, 65157693),
             "Jun 19" = c(50807257, 88475934))
names(df)[2:7] <- c("Jan 19", "Feb 19", "Mar 19", "Apr 19", "May 19", "Jun 19")
```

When next you write a question, it will help others to include that. :-) Now that we've got some dummy data to work with, I get the same result when I do

```
 gather(df, "Jan 19", "Feb 19", "Mar 19", "Apr 19", "May 19", "Jun 19", 
                   key = "Product", value = "Volume")
```

as when I do

```
 gather(df, key = "Product", value = "Volume", -Designation)
```

with the latter not requiring you to specify the months as you add them. If you've already tried that, then I'm not able to replicate your problem. If you haven't, well, then there's a possible answer.

I still suspect that the spaces in the column names is throwing off something because R really isn't meant to have spaces in column names. If you can fix that, I'd recommend doing so.

Also, the data.frame you're starting with is wide; is there a reason you can't read it in to make it narrow? No need to answer that question here; it's just a general approach that will likely help you out in the future because long data.frames are often easier to work with and require less memory than wide data.frames. If you could start with the long version of your data and then add new rows each month instead of new columns, that would probably help.

Comment: Thanks LauraS.  The "-Designation" worked.

I have contemplated pulling the data into a narrow table, but there's other data it's joining due to other data needs.  Appreciate the help...

Answer (score 0):

I tried replicating your problem with some dummy data:

```
 df <- data.frame(Product = LETTERS[1:20],
             Jan19 = rnorm(20), Feb19 = rnorm(20), Mar19 = rnorm(20), 
             Apr19 = rnorm(20), May19 = rnorm(20), May19 = rnorm(20),
             Jun19 = rnorm(20))
 names(df) <- sub("19", " 19", names(df))
```

I'm not positive this is what your data look like, though, and the result when I apply the command you listed above on this data.frame is odd and probably not what you're looking for. Two thoughts:

1. If I've got your data structure roughly correct, maybe the spaces in the column names are throwing things off. Try renaming your columns. You could do that by switching what I've got above, so `names(df) <- sub(" [0-9]", "", names(df))`, for example.
2. Are you sure you're gathering the variables you mean to gather? What would make more sense to me -- again, only if I'm correctly guessing the contents of your data.frame -- would be this: `Gatherresult <- gather(df, key = Month, value = Volume, -Product)`

Comment: I'll try changing the column names, but confident I'm gathering the right data.  There are two designations that I'm looking to plot against each other.  At the moment the table is wide, Designation (2 rows, Earn, Non-Earn) and then volumes of each designation for each month.  I'm gathering in order to plot the earn vs non-earn.  So each month I add a column.  Just trying to avoid having to edit the code each month (adding the column name).

Comment: If you show some reproducible data, that will help greatly. :-)

Comment: Here's the source table:


+-------------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----------+
| Designation |  Jan 19  | Feb 19  |  Mar 19  | Apr 19  |  May 19  |  Jun 19  |
+-------------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----------+
| NonR        |  3529735 |  359615 | 13860320 |   31385 | 33026202 | 50807257 |
| R           | 12092371 | 2810619 |  7110432 | 1304819 | 65157693 | 88475934 |
+-------------+----------+---------+----------+---------+----------+----------+